# Error fetching servicenow tickets in Python

Tags: python, servicenow

I am trying to fetch tickets from a ServiceNow instance of its delta data. For which I am using [pysnow](https://github.com/rbw0/pysnow) lib. I am writing the output of the fetched service now incidents into a CSV file. I am facing the following error if I run the script.

Note: Tried using Python 2.7 & Python 3.5

```
linux-instance:/opt/data$ sudo python3 /opt/scripts/incident-fetcher.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scripts/incident-fetcher.py", line 31, in <module>
    for row in r.get_all():
  File "/home/azuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysnow.py", line 341, in _all_inner
    yield self._get_content(response)
  File "/home/azuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysnow.py", line 507, in _get_content
    return content_json['result']

KeyError: 'result'
```

Code here : https://gist.github.com/shawkath/1c51779f9082160140a52d4039a16bfb

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Hi mic4ael, I have added a Gist file in the question. Please check. Much appreciated.